# How to translate alertController and mat-snackbar message by using ngx-translate?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, ionic4, ngx-translate

I'm creating ionic 4 angular app, and using ngx-translate to translate 1 or more languages.by using ngx-translate it is easy to translate in html.but how to translate text message in alertController and mat-snackbar messages.

```
 //using below ngx-translate
 import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

 constructor(public translate:TranslateService){}

 //Alert Controller
 async alert_Massage() {
 let alertMassage = await this.alertController.create({
  message: "How are you ?",//how to translate this message.
  buttons: ['Ok'],
});
await alertMassage.present();
}

//mat-snackbar //how to translate this some error message 
this.snackBar.open('Some Error messages', 'Ok', {
        verticalPosition: 'top',
        duration: 2000,
        panelClass: ['red-snackbar']
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get translations from service:

```
const translations = await this.translate.get([ 'How are you?' ])}).toPromise();
let alertMassage = await this.alertController.create({
  message: translations['How are you?'].
  buttons: ['Ok'],
});
await alertMassage.present();
```

Comment: this is not translate . same msg display in alert How are you ?

Comment: If you use your default translation, it is. If you want to change language, you should set it with :  translate.use(translate.getBrowserLang().match(/en|fr|hu/) ? translate.getBrowserLang() : 'en');

Comment: i have 2 json file 1 for english and 2nd for spanish . i'm written english and spanish key value translate.

Comment: call before geting the translation to get spanish translation: this.translate.use('es');

Comment: i understand .Thank you.